# Trigger the training of my packaged model with cloud function from google storage ***SOLVED**

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines

The approach used in this post is obsolete: you can find the solution by using VertexAI in the post linked below:

[Automate batch predictions with VertexAI pipeline and Kuberflow component ***SOLVED***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893368/automate-batch-predictions-with-vertexai-pipeline-and-kuberflow-component-sol)

###############################

I am new with cloud functions and AI Platform Pipeline.

I have my customised model stored in GCS that I run from my laptop with the script training.sh

where training.sh is

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training model_training_$now \
--scale-tier basic \
--packages gs://my_project_bucket/my_package_model-0.1.2.tar.gz \
--module-name model.train_pipeline \
--job-dir=gs://my_project_bucket/trained_model \
--region europe-west1 \
--runtime-version=2.5 \
--python-version=3.7 \
-- \
--user_first_arg=first_arg_value --user_second_arg=second_arg_value
```

I am trying to automate the training every time a new file is uploaded in the input_data bucket. I am using cloud functions to do this. However it is not clear to me how to use Kuberflow to run the training.sh file.

I am using this tutorial

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/using-remote-and-event-triggered-ai-platform-pipelines

and its notebook

https://github.com/amygdala/code-snippets/blob/master/ml/notebook_examples/functions/hosted_kfp_gcf.ipynb

Here he defines a sequential pipeline by creating containers.

```
def sequential_pipeline(filename='gs://ml-pipeline-playground/shakespeare1.txt'):
   """A pipeline with two sequential steps."""
   op1 = dsl.ContainerOp(
       name='filechange',
       image='library/bash:4.4.23',
       command=['sh', '-c'],
       arguments=['echo "%s" > /tmp/results.txt' % filename],
       file_outputs={'newfile': '/tmp/results.txt'})
   op2 = dsl.ContainerOp(
       name='echo',
       image='library/bash:4.4.23',
       command=['sh', '-c'],
       arguments=['echo "%s"' % op1.outputs['newfile']]
       )
```

I cannot see how to define a similar function to run my training.sh. Do I need to containerise my model package my_package_model-0.1.2.tar.gz?

Is anyone familiar with this type of automation?

Comment: I think this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/executing-bash-scripts-with-a-webhook-in-google-cloud-75ea4b173c9) answers your question. Let me know if it does.

Comment: Hello! thanks a lot @Wytrzymały Wiktor. I am trying to solve it by calling the using the Google API Client Library for Python as explained here. https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/training-jobs#python

Comment: Thanks a lot @FaridShumbar, I think I will try your solution for another similar problem. But for this one, since it a ML deployment, I will use the tool suggested by Google like the API Client Library for python or Kuberflow.

Comment: @Annalix it looks like you've found a solution. Could you also post it here as an answer to help community members who encounter the same question? Thanks

Comment: thanks @FaridShumbar, will do